# Adding custom customer attribute with declarative schema and db_schema

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom, customer-attribute

I added a custom attribute in de customer_entity table with db_schema.xml. I can get the value of that attribute with getdata('debtor_id') but I can't set it with setData('debtor_id' ,2).

Did I miss a step?

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
 
    <table name="customer_entity">
        <column  xsi:type="int" name="debtor_id" padding="11" unsigned="false" nullable="true" identity="false"  comment="Debtor ID" />
    </table>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added a **field** inside **customer_entity** table, if you want to create a **custom customer attribute** you have to create a custom attribute by implementing **Setup\Patch** functions.

Refer this: [SampleEavAttribute](https://github.com/manavluhar/Codilar_SampleEavAttribute)

Remove the column and do **setup:upgrade**. after that, check in the database whether that field is removed or not. if it's not removed then you have to remove it. later try to implement using the suggested way.

Comment: Do i need to remove the column from my db_schema.xml before making a setup/patch?

Comment: Yes, remove the entry from the db_schema.xml and try from the setup patch data.

Answer (score 0):

> We Strongly recommend please try to create an EAV attribute with the help of setup patch data. I have added a reference
>
> Path Prince\CusEavAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Prince All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Prince\CusEavAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class AddIsSaveBrowserHistoryCustomerAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetup
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var SetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        
        /** @var $attributeSet Set */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'save_history',
            [
                'label' => 'Save History',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'type' => 'static',
                'source' => '',
                'default' => 1,
                'required' => false,
                'position' => 333,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
        
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_save_browser_history');
        $attribute->addData([
            'used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId
        
        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'is_save_browser_history');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
        
        ];
    }
}
```